# How to Show apache error on shared hosting?

Tags: php, error-reporting

I have tried to show the errors on the server by adding this :

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1)
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors', 1); 
ini_set('error_log', '/home/*****/error_log.txt'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

on top of the main page.

i also tryed to output the errors using [ChromePhp](http://www.chromephp.com/) and [FireBug](http://www.chromephp.com/) but it's not working.

I don't have enough permission to change the server configuration.

Comment: Since you used shared hosting why not ask their support? it varies from web host to web host and logging may already be available though a control panel, or outside the htdocs folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving this

```
error_reporting(4037);
```

if this won't work then go to your write down below code

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(ini_get_all()):
echo '</pre>';
```

and check permission of "error_reporting" if its "6" or "7" then only you can set error reporting run time otherwise not.

furthermore you can ask your hosting provider what to do.